# Filter and retrieve required value from csv file python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv text file. Its contents look like this:

```
name,age,gender
A,10,M
B,12,M
C,10,F
D,15,F
E,10,M
F,12,F
G,12,M
```

I want to retrieve only the rows having age value equal to 10 (example. rows 3 and 5).

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: Can you post the code that you've written so far and what the fault is?

Comment: SO is not place when someone does all work for you (and for free). Please show us what you've got so far, we can help you with particular problem.

Comment: take a look to this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: @leigh  , i'm very new to python and i've not used python's csv library, so i was looking just for reference rather than code itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are new to Python and it's just 3 lines of code, here your are:

```
import csv

with open('text.csv', 'rt') as f:
    age10 = [row for row in csv.reader(f) if row[1] == '10']
```

This gives you a list of lists matching age == '10':

[['A', '10', 'M'], ['C', '10', 'F'], ['E', '10', 'M']]

If you get stuck with the offical docs it's always good to take a look at "Module of the week":
http://pymotw.com/2/csv/